# tar command unable to add attachment files in unix sun solaris

Tags: shell, unix

I have been passing the attachment filenames to the program and the tar command unable to create archive for the attachment files and attachment files can contain spaces in their filenames . Can somebody help me in identifying the root cause

Here the atachment files are **"v Al 2015-0974_ca.pdf" "v Al 2015-0974_ma.pdf"**

```
ksh testing.ksh 2015-0974.htm '"v Al 2015-0974_ca.pdf" "v Al 2015-0974_ma.pdf"' Int 5
```

**testing.ksh**

```
  FILE=${1}                             
  ATTACHEDFILES="${2}"
  echo ${ATTACHEDFILES}
  TARGETENV=${3}                              
  PRIORITY=${4}                                

  FNWP=${FILE%.*}                           
  EXT=${FILE#*.}                           
  FN=${FNWP##*/}

val="tar cvf ${FN}.tar title html email delivertime "${ATTACHEDFILES}""
echo $val
package=${PRIORITY}_$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")_eytaxalert.nwf
gzip -cv ${FN}.tar > ${package}

exit 0
```

**Output:**

```
a title 1K
a html 33K
a email 4K
2015-0974.tar
```

**Expected Output:**

```
a title 1K
a html 33K
a email 4K
a v Al 2015-0974_ca.pdf 20K
a v Al 2015-0974_ma.pdf 15K
2015-0974.tar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
testing.ksh 2015-0974.htm '"v Al 2015-0974_ca.pdf" "v Al 2015-0974_ma.pdf"' Int 5
```

Invokes the `testing.ksh` script with four parameters, which are literally:

```
2015-0974.htm
"v Al 2015-0974_ca.pdf" "v Al 2015-0974_ma.pdf"
Int
5
```

Note that the second parameter is a single string with four quote marks embedded in it. You then assign that to `$ATTACHEDFILES` and (I think) execute the following (my doubt comes from the fact that you merely echo this in the snippet in your question, but I'm guessing that you pasted a debugging version):

```
tar cvf ${FN}.tar title html email delivertime "${ATTACHEDFILES}"
```

That calls tar with seven arguments

```
cvf
2015-0974.tar
title
html
email
delivertime
"v Al 2015-0974_ca.pdf" "v Al 2015-0974_ma.pdf"
```

`tar` will interpret the first argument as anoption string, the second one as a filename for the newly-created tarfile (because of the `f` in the option string), and the remaining five as filenames. Since `"v Al 2015-0974_ca.pdf" "v Al 2015-0974_ma.pdf"` is not the name of an existing file, it is not added to the tarfile.

What you intended was to invoke tar with these arguments:

```
cvf
2015-0974.tar
title
html
email
delivertime
v Al 2015-0974_ca.pdf
v Al 2015-0974_ma.pdf
```

Like pretty well every other programming language, in bash quotes are *part of the syntax*. The string created does not include the quotes. If you do insert quotes into a string (by escaping them, or using two types of quoting as in your example), then the string has quotes in it. It doesn't get scanned again.

If you want to provide a list of filenames on the command line and the filenames need to be quoted, you need to quote them individually. Since your script will not be able to know how many filenames there are, it is best to put the list at the end. You can refer to a list of arguments using the slice syntax (in either bash or ksh93): `"${@:4}"` is the list of verbatim arguments (exactly as provided to the script) starting with argument 4. `"${@:4:2}"` would be precisely two arguments starting with argument 4, but I think in this case you would want all of the arguments to the end. Note that the quotes in that syntax are required; they are what indicate that the arguments should be passed through as is, rather than being wordsplit.

So your script might look something like this:

```
FILE=${1}
TARGETENV=${2}                              
PRIORITY=${3}                                

FNWP=${FILE%.*}                           
EXT=${FILE#*.}                           
FN=${FNWP##*/}

tar cvf "${FN}.tar" title html email delivertime "${@:4}"
```

and would be called like this:

```
ksh testing.ksh 2015-0974.htm Int 5 "v Al 2015-0974_ca.pdf" "v Al 2015-0974_ma.pdf"
```

**Edit:**

- Before Solaris 11, the `ksh` shell was ksh88, not ksh93, so the above will not work. See below. Apparently, there is a ksh93 implementation available as `dtksh`.
- In case the non-standard syntax `"${@:4}"` doesn't work, here is a simple Posix-compatible alternative:

  ```
  FILE=${1}
  TARGETENV=${2}                              
  PRIORITY=${3}
  # Remove the three arguments from the argument list:
  shift 3

  FNWP=${FILE%.*}                           
  EXT=${FILE#*.}                           
  FN=${FNWP##*/}

  tar cvf "${FN}.tar" title html email delivertime "${@}"
  ```

Comment: rici: "${@:4}" command is not working and throwing an error : Bad substitution. So will this command work on Sun solaris ?

Comment: @praveen: are you sure that you are using ksh or bash on the Solaris system? Perhaps your script has a `#!/bin/sh` shebang line? Anyway, I edited the answer to provide a posix-compatible alternative.

Comment: I am using ksh in solaris

Comment: @Praveen: Apparently, `ksh` in Solaris (before Solaris 11) is ksh88, not ksh93. The `${@:start:count}` syntax was added in ksh93. Apparently, there is a ksh93 implementation called  `/usr/dt/bin/dtksh`. In Solaris 11, the default shell and `/usr/bin/ksh` were both changed to ksh93.